# Populating a MultiChoiceItem Dialog interface with ArrayList / CharSequence[] (dynamic data)

Tags: android, arraylist, android-dialog

I've been trying to implement an ArrayAdapter or ArrayList into a custom dialog through its builder, as I need the ability to multiselect, and at same time the list items are going to be dynamic(fetching from database).

```
alertDialogBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, checkedItems, listener);
```

In my case I need the `items` to be populated by an `ArrayList<String>` or `ArrayList<CharSequence>` but i can't seem to get them working.

The type of MultiChoice dialog i mentioned is similar to this [android-spinner-like-ui-for-selecting-multiple-options](http://chrisblunt.com/2011/03/01/android-spinner-like-ui-for-selecting-multiple-options/)

[image]

I've tried searching but the only solutions i get are for single choice items. The `builder.setAdapter(ListAdapter, OnClickListener)` method only allows an OnClickListener while i need a DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener instead. Can anyone kindly enlighten me a little? Thanks!

Comment: why not create a `boolean[] selected = new boolean[yourArraylist.size()];` which is all false and inside the onClickListener set the `selected[which]` to true?

Comment: I can try that and make do without the 'OnMultiChoiceClickListener' if it works, but before that stage, do you know how i can populate the dialog through ArrayList or ArrayAdapter? thanks!

Comment: I have this already done .. Unfortunately before creating the dialog i created a `CharSequence[]` and a `boolean[]`. If your `ArrayList` if of `CharSequence` type, you can use the `toArray()` function